# PSET 3 for CS50 - Recover.c - My JPEG files are recovered but they are all empty

Tags: jpeg, cs50

So I am currently attempting recover.c from the cs50 pset3 and I have recovered all 49 jpeg files. However, all these jpeg files are empty (with a grey and white grid). Could someone please explain where my code went wrong? I tried check50 to see if my code was correct but it said the recovered images do not match.

I changed my "w" to "wb" in my fopen function too but that didn't seem to work either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//a data type that can store a byte
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

//Checking to see if there is only one command line argument
if (argc != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover image\n" );
    return 1;
}

//Opening the file to see if its correct

char *infile = argv[1];
FILE *memory = fopen(infile, "r");
if (memory == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
    return 2;
}

//Creation of a buffer
BYTE buffer[512] = {0};
//Whether or not we have found a JPEG or not
bool jpegfound = false;
//the number of JPEG files found
int numJPEGfile = 0;
//declaring the new to be JPEG file so that it has a scope for the 
whole while loop
FILE *img = NULL;
//declaring the new JPEG filename
char filename[8];

//Repeating until the end of card
while(fread(buffer, 512, 1, memory) == 1)
{

    //Start of a new JPEG?
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        jpegfound = true;
        sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", numJPEGfile);
        numJPEGfile += 1;
        img = fopen(filename, "wb");
        fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);

    }

    //Have we already found a JPEG?
    if(jpegfound)
    {
        jpegfound = false;
        fclose(img);

    }


}

//Close any remaining files
fclose(memory);
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the below command in the terminal, how large are the jpg-files you recovered? I think this will give you a hint for solving this pset.

```
ls -l
```